# Cannot find element by xpath, selenium

Tags: python, selenium

I want to scrape song titles from Shazam.

I managed to log in but when I try to get the titles by xpath, selenium does not manage to find elements. I think the problem is that shazam is a dynamic website.

[code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9AP2O.png)

Comment: You should probably use `find_elements` not `element` it makes sense there is more than one `title`...

Comment: yes exactly like @MosheSlavin said. ( sorry i didnt notice your comment here and i posted an answer )

Comment: Please read why [a screenshot of code is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Paste the code and properly format it instead.

Answer (score 2):

"scrape song titles "

I would recommend to change `find_element_by_xpath` to `find_elements_by_xpath` becuase you are looking for more then 1 element. After that you can itterate through this list of elements

Answer (score 0):

Your code is correct but the element(`//div[@class='title']`) that you are searching is not there in that page, check it once again by manually inspecting.

Below is your modified code, to get the title - you need to call `title` on the `driver` object :

```
from selenium import webdriver
from time import sleep
driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:\\NotBackedUp\\chromedriver.exe')
driver.get("https://www.shazam.com/myshazam")
print("Before switching title : ", driver.title)
sleep(3)

window_before = driver.window_handles[0]
driver.find_element_by_xpath("(//div[@id='/login/app/myshazam']/a)[1]").click()
window_after = driver.window_handles[1]
driver.switch_to_window(window_after)
print("After switching title : ", driver.title)
driver.find_element_by_id("email").send_keys('some email')
driver.find_element_by_id("pass").send_keys('some password')
driver.find_element_by_id("loginbutton").click()

driver.switch_to_window(window_before)
print("After switching back title : ", driver.title)
```

I hope it helps...